# Getting Unexpected Token ILLEGAL JS Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I keep getting the "Unexpected Token ILLEGAL" error when on the script once its registered on the page.

```
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                 str.Append("<script type='text/javascript'> function AnotherFunction(evt) { ");
                str.Append("var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();");

                str.Append("var data = new FormData();");
                str.Append("var files = $('#FileUpload1').get(0).files;");
                str.Append("for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){");
                str.Append("data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);}");
                str.Append("xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress' , function (evt){");
                str.Append("if (evt.lengthComputable) {");
                str.Append(" var progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);");
                str.Append("$('#progressbar').progressbar('value', progress); }}, false);");
                str.Append("  xhr.open('POST', 'Handler.ashx');");
                str.Append("xhr.send(data); $('#progressbar').progressbar({");
                str.Append(" max: 100,change: function (evt, ui){");
                str.Append("$('#progresslabel').text($('#progressbar').progressbar('value') + '%');");
                str.Append(" }, complete: function (evt, ui){");
                str.Append("  $('#progresslabel').text('File upload successful!');' }});");
                str.Append("evt.preventDefault(); }</script>");


                ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshParent", str.ToString(), false);
```

Does anyone have ideas on how this can be resolved?

Comment: More important than the error.. In order to debug this code,  take the appended string (the JS) and isolate it. You can throw the script tag into a blank page, and use firefox's tools to prettify it (correct indentation and such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra `'` in your penultimate str.Append() call.

Change

`str.Append("  $('#progresslabel').text('File upload successful!');' }});");`

to

`str.Append("  $('#progresslabel').text('File upload successful!'); }});");`

Comment: Ha, this is one of those times when I should just take a break and let my eyes rest before I continue to debug. Thank you Sir. I will mark answer once I am allowed.